# Authentic English translation of Shiv Puran

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana

I have looked this up on internet and found JL Shashtri translation of Shiv Purana but many people have told me that it is not accurate and author have put his own views instead in many places.So i am looking for good translation. Thanks